# Complex zeroes of Error Function and Parabolic Cylinder Function.

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, mathematical-physics

Does there exist EXACT zeros of Error Function (Erfc(z)) and Parabolic Cylinder Function ($D_v(z)$)(http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ParabolicCylinderD/). Here (https://dlmf.nist.gov/12) (section 12.2 and 12.11) is the discussion about the real zeros of $D_v(z)$ but I don't understand about the complex zeros. I am particularly interested for the exact complex zeros of $D_{-\frac{1}{2}}(z)$ and $D_{-\frac{1}{2}}(iz)$.

I think I would be able to proceed on my work, if equivalently, I know if there exists a zero (except $z=0$) of error function.

Answer (score 1):

Both erfc and $D_{-1/2}$ have infinitely many complex zeros.  I doubt very much that you'll get closed forms for them.  The closest zeros to $0$ for $\text{erfc}$ are approximately
$-1.354810128 \pm 1.991466843 i$.  The closest zeros to $0$ for $\text{D}_{-1/2}$ are approximately $-2.110851502 \pm 2.267049242 i$.

Here are the zeros of erfc (red) and $D_{-1/2}$ (blue) for $-10 < \text{Re}(z), \text{Im}(z) < 10$.

[image]

Comment: Just existential proof of such  zeros for $D_{-\frac{1}{2}}$ would work for me! Please share if you know the references. Furthermore, I am precisely looking for at least one non-zero zero (with nonzero imaginary part) of function  $r(z)=  a D_{-\frac{1}{2}}(z) + b  D_{-\frac{1}{2}}(iz)$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: If you can approximate $D_{-1/2}$ (or any other analytic function $f$) numerically to a given accuracy, you can prove existence of a zero in a region bounded by a curve by integrating $f'/f$ around the curve.

Comment: I don't know any good references on this stuff. Do't understand how to proceed. Could you please be more specific like how to approximate $D_{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: There is a representation of $D_v(z)$ through confluent hypergeometric function (http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ParabolicCylinderD/26/01/01/). I think there is some on the zeros of confluent hypergeometric function (e.g; here https://ac.els-cdn.com/0021904582900764/1-s2.0-0021904582900764-main.pdf?_tid=c82be8b8-2323-49de-a3ea-b39e94bdf685&acdnat=1545840621_614bb10f30036d3b99203da17903afd8). In this paper at page 5, the bounds for zeros are given for real parameters $a$ and $c$. If the parameters are real in confluent hypergeo function, does its zeros are always real?

Answer (score 0):

You need the inverse function given with [**Bessel Y Zero $\text y_{v,x}$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselYZero):

$$\frac{\text D_{-\frac12}\left(iy\right)}{\text D_{-\frac12}\left(y\right)}=-e^{2ix}\implies y=(1-i)\sqrt{2\text y_{\frac14,\Bbb N-\frac{\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))}\pi}}, x\in\Bbb R $$

[**which works**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bparaboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2Ci+x%29%2Fparaboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2C+x%29-%28-e%5E%282i+eulergamma%29%29%2C10%5D%2Cx%3D%281-i%29sqrt%282+BesselYZero%281%2F4%2C3-atan%28tan%28eulergamma%29%29%2Fpi%29%29) with the $n$th natural number giving the $n$th solution

Another presentation is:

$$\frac{\text D_{-\frac12}\left(iy\right)}{\text D_{-\frac12}\left(y\right)}= \frac{x+i}{x-i}\implies y=(1-i)\sqrt{2\text y_{\frac14,\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}\pi+\Bbb N}}, x\in\Bbb R $$

[which also works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bparaboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2Ci+x%29%2Fparaboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2C+x%29-%283%2Bi%29%2F%283-i%29%2C10%5D%2Cx%3D%281-i%29sqrt%282+BesselYZero%281%2F4%2C2%2Batan%283%29%2Fpi%29%29) with the $n$th solution from the $n$ natural number.

Both of these solutions partly solve your $r(z)=a\operatorname D_{-\frac12}(z)+b\operatorname D_{-\frac12}(iz)$