# Convert the Bessel ratio $\frac{ J_\frac34(x)}{J_{-\frac34}(x)}$ into a simple ratio of parabolic cylinder $D_v(x)$ functions

Tags: complex-numbers, special-functions, inverse-function, bessel-functions, rational-functions

We use [Bessel $I_v(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Bessel+I), [Bessel $J_v(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Bessel+J), [**Parabolic Cylinder $D_v(x)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Parabolic+Cylinder+D), and [Bessel Y Zero $y_{v,x}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Bessel+Y+Zero)

**Question:**

The goal is to find the simplest parabolic cylinder equation that $y_{\frac34,x}$ solves. A partial solution is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B%28ddx%28Paraboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2Ce%5E%28i+pi%2F4%29x%29-%28-1%29%5E%281%2F4%29Paraboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2Ce%5E%28-i+pi%2F4%29x%29%29%29%2C20%5D%2Cx%3D+2sqrt%28BesselYZero%283%2F4%2C+2-3%2F8%29%29). Please see the motivation section for the $v=\frac14$ solution. *However*, the first step is to simplify: $$\frac{J_\frac34(x)}{J_{-\frac34}(x)}=\text{Rational expression in terms of }D_v(x) $$ and use algebra to isolate the parabolic cylinder functions as much as possible. Let’s introduce the DLMF [Parabolic Cylinder $\text W(a,x)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.14), it’s derivative wrt $x$ function, and [**this identity**](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.16#E4):
$$\frac{J_\frac34(x)}{J_{-\frac34}(x)} =\frac{W’(0,2\sqrt x)-W’(0,-2\sqrt x)}{W’(0,2\sqrt x)+W’(0,-2\sqrt x)}$$

Now use [**this conversion formula**](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.14#iv) and [a change of notation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.2#E5) to possibly get:

$$\frac2{\frac{J_\frac34\left(\frac{x^2}4\right)}{J_{-\frac34} \left(\frac{x^2}4\right)} +1}-1=\frac{ W’(0,-x)}{W’(0,x)} \mathop=^{\large ?} i(\sqrt2+1)\frac{\frac d{dx}\left(D_{-\frac12}\left(\sqrt[-4]{-1}x\right)-\sqrt[4]{-1} D_{-\frac12}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1}x\right)\right)}{\frac d{dx} \left(D_{-\frac12}\left(\sqrt[-4]{-1}\right)+\sqrt[4]{-1} D_{-\frac12}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1}x\right)\right)}$$

However, [expanding](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx%28Paraboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2Ce%5E%28i+pi%2F4%29x%29%2B%28-1%29%5E%281%2F4%29Paraboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2Ce%5E%28-i+pi%2F4%29x%29%29) the derivatives gives complicated expressions. Is there any way to simplify $\frac{W’(0,-x)}{W’(0,x)}$ or $\frac{J_\frac34(x)}{J_{-\frac34}(x)}$ into a simple ratio of $D_v(x)$?. The following identity may help simplify it:

$$\frac{a-by}{a+by}=\frac2{\frac ba y+1}-1$$

**Motivation:**

$$\frac{D_{-\frac12}(iz)}{D_{-\frac12}(z)}=\frac{I_{-\frac14}\left(\frac{z^2}4\right)-I_{-\frac14}\left(-\frac{z^2}4\right)}{I_{-\frac14}\left(\frac{z^2}4\right)-I_{-\frac14}\left(\frac{z^2}4\right)},\text{Re}(z)>\text{Im}(z)$$ and an inverse function from

> [Complex zeroes of Error Function and Parabolic Cylinder Function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052630/complex-zeroes-of-error-function-and-parabolic-cylinder-function/4514624#4514624)

$$\frac{D_{-\frac12}\left(iy\right)}{D_{-\frac12}\left(y\right)}=-e^{2ix}\implies y=(1-i)\sqrt{2y_{\frac14,\Bbb N-\frac{\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))}\pi}}, x\in\Bbb R $$ [which works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bparaboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2Ci+x%29%2Fparaboliccylinderd%28-1%2F2%2C+x%29-%28-e%5E%282i+eulergamma%29%29%2C10%5D%2Cx%3D%281-i%29sqrt%282+BesselYZero%281%2F4%2C3-atan%28tan%28eulergamma%29%29%2Fpi%29%29) with the $n$th natural number giving the $n$th solution.